# Generating random noise for fun in /dev/snd/

Tags: audio, alsa

Recently I have been exploring the enchanted /dev folder. I want to write some random data to an audio device in order to generate some noise.

I am using ALSA.

So I instruct cat to pipe some random data to the playback file in the /dev folder...

```
 cat file-of-random-data > /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
```

then I recieve what seems to be an error from cat

```
 cat: write error: File descriptor in bad state
```

How can I fix this so I can hear some delicious static play from my sound card?

Comment: I think you need to send random [PCM data](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html), or maybe you need to set up the device with a few ioctls first — you can't just dump random bytes.

Comment: @Gilles According to Wikipedia, .wav is PCM and I get exactly the same result when replace the random file with a .wav file. I will investigate setting up some in/out controls.

Comment: Does someone have a pointer for a tutorial on how to set up some ioctls? For something called ioctls, I thought ALSA as an API should provide the interface for input and output?

Comment: Here is a working example how to write pcm data directly to the device file: http://github.com/igor-liferenko/pcm

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think the reason this isn't working for you is because that interface has been deprecated. You normally can't write audio using `/dev/dsp` anymore, at least without being tricky.

There is a program that will accomplish this for you on your system: `padsp`.
This will map the `/dev/audio` or `/dev/dsp` file to the new Audio Server system.

Fire up the terminal and get into root mode with `sudo su`.

Then, I'm going to `cat /dev/urandom` and pipe the output into `padsp` and use the `tee` command to send the data to `/dev/audio`. You'll get a ton of garbage in your terminal, so you may want to redirect to `/dev/null`.

Once you're in superuser, try this command:

```
cat /dev/urandom | padsp tee /dev/audio > /dev/null
```

You may even want to try with other devices, like your mouse: Use: `/dev/psaux`, for instance or the usb driver. You can even run your memory through it:
`/dev/mem`

Hope this clarifies why it wasn't working before.

Personally, I found the mouse and memory to be way more interesting than playing random static!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. Answered a full 7 months after posting the question! :-)

Comment: It seems that `sudo` privileges are not required for this.

Comment: thanks very much. i found binaries to be weirdly interesting. things like /usr/bin/ls  /usr/bin/gnome-terminal /usr/bin/mysql

Comment: hmm, strange, 'tee' can do this but 'dd of=/dev/audio' cannot.

Comment: @Jasen dd may be writing too much at a time. padsp simulates /dev/audio to redirect it through alsa. dd without padsp will not even see /dev/audio unless in-kernel OSS emulation is enabled (and by default it isn't). And I think writing a large block, much larger than the in-driver buffers, could even fail.

Answer (score 13):

`cat /dev/urandom | aplay`
is the command that needs to be typed. If you aren't in "audio" group, you could prefix aplay with sudo. This also doesn't interfere with any daemons (I was running `pulseaudio` while this command was active and correctly heard the "noise".

EDIT (Aug 6, 2019): In an older version of the command I also had a `padsp tee` thing between the `cat` and `aplay`. Now that I'm actually working in the field I realise that it made absolutely no sense. Also, I know the updated command (the one visible now at the beginning of this answer) works because I use it several times a day at work.

Comment: I use ALSA, and "padsp tee" isn't necessary.

Comment: In my pulseaudio experiences (and whatever Ubuntu is using when PA is down) that `padsp tee` was required (I had precise 12.04.2 at that time) The thing is you shouldn't try to dump data directly into devices, even if you were root (as far as I know few files are readable and none writable in the /dev folder), because you could either get an error (in the best case, which gets more common with each update), crash the kernel or even break the device, in rare cases. One should use unprivileged elements, like aplay, to do this (audio group or root required, unfortunately). @geremia

Comment: Funny how now I see that the `padsp tee` thing actually doesn't make any sense AT ALL. At work I use something similar without that line to test that I'm making progress with writing the audio driver. Will now update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try /dev/audio or one of the other devices under /dev/snd. Not all of them are audio data sinks, you might have caught a mixer, microphone, or something

Comment: thanks for the reply. According to /proc/asound/devices  /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p is the right device for audio playback (hence the 'p')

Comment: Also, I am not sure, but can there be multiple dev "files" for playback? I _don't_ have a '/dev/audio' I think '/dev/audio' has something to do with OSS which is used on older kernels (before 2.5)

Answer (score 2):

Is a sound daemon (e.g. `pulseaudio`) holding a lock on the device?  I think you can find out if anything else has a handle on it via `lsof`.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestion. I had a check, using `grep` and `lsof`. `pulseaudio` is using `/dev/snd/controlC0` but it isn't on `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p` . I had a double check by going to `/var/lock` to find if there was a file for a lock on the device. `ls -al` tells that the folder is empty. So I guess there is no lock on pcmC0D0p

Comment: @jones Holding a lock on the control may be enough to lock the whole card, depending on the driver. (sorry for answering after 8 years, now I learnt that myself)

Answer (score 2):

**update** (2020-12-25): I created a shell script for forwarding data from stdin to stdout which set up stdout if it is a PCM file. Check out https://github.com/psqli/pcmsh.

TL;DR: The device's parameters must be set before reading or writing data to it.

Step by step:

1. Open the PCM device. E.g.: `fd = open("/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p", O_RDWR)`. After open, PCM is in `OPEN` state.
2. Set parameters with `ioctl(fd, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_HW_PARAMS, (struct snd_pcm_hw_params*) p)`. The hardware parameters structure has *masks* (each bit is a value) and *intervals* ([minimum, maximum] range). The parameters that are not being set must be passed filled (all bits/values set for masks; full range for intervals). After setting hardware parameters, PCM is in `SETUP` state. See [pcm_set_config()](https://github.com/tinyalsa/tinyalsa/blob/1923b9b0fd7116ba235a812ef00fd6c7c9ed363d/src/pcm.c#L341) of TinyALSA for code.

   Setting `ACCESS`, `FORMAT`, `RATE`, `CHANNELS`, `PERIOD_SIZE` and `PERIODS` is sufficient. The other parameters are variants of these, except `BUFFER_SIZE` that in some devices may be set to a non multiple of `PERIOD_SIZE`.
3. Call `ioctl(fd, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_PREPARE)` to prepare device and ALSA runtime variables. After this, the PCM is in `PREPARED` state.
4. Start reading (capture) or writing (playback).

A minimal application for reading or writing to a PCM device will have most of its code around hardware parameters manipulation.

Comment: I'm not sure if actual read/write work, as aplay uses (at least on the system I'm developing on) ioctl(fd, SNDRV_PCM_IOCTL_WRITEI_FRAMES, ...) and not an actual write() call on playback. Does ALSA itself have a wrapper that takes the read/write entry points and translates them to the ioctl's?

Comment: @PaulStelian Yes. See [the definition of file operations for pcm](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/tree/sound/core/pcm_native.c?h=sound-5.3-rc7#n3684). In `snd_pcm_read()` and `snd_pcm_write()`, [bytes are converted to frames](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/tree/sound/core/pcm_native.c?h=sound-5.3-rc7#n3059).

Comment: Thanks, I'll be playing with this sometime soon, I hope.