# Make noise on Ubuntu 18.04 without internet

Tags: audio, bell

I have an Ubuntu machine that currently has no internet connection. I want to set it up so it makes a sound when internet comes back.

I'm not sure this machine has a PC speaker, but there is a speaker connected to the on-board sound card.

In the past I think I used `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/audio` for this, but this doesn't seem to work anymore.

None of these tools are currently installed: `beep`, `aplay`, `padsp`

None of these made any sound:

```
modprobe pcspkr
echo -e '\a' > /dev/tty1
echo -e '\a' > /dev/console
```

This failed with `write error: File descriptor in bad state`:

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
```

Comment: Is PulseAudio running? I don't know whether it's part of the default server installation.

Comment: @Gilles No, it's not installed: `Command 'pulseaudio' not found, but can be installed with: apt install pulseaudio`

Comment: `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p` does not work. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/529915/197194).

Answer (score 1):

Your `echo` command might failed because the bell might be **disabled** via `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc` like something with either one of these :

```
set bell-style none
set bell-style visible
```

Or it could also be your terminal that have bell sound disabled.

You also need to check that there is no

```
setterm -blength 0
```

in any of you profile shell script like `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` or in your `$HOME`.

So you better try the `beep` command that really use the **on-board-speaker** and not *echo* command that goes through different layer (where it could be blocked) to finally get the beep sound.

Note, however that you might need to run beep with **root** privilege for it to work. aka `sudo beep`

Are you sure, you have **an on-board pc-speaker** ? We don't talk about the built-in speaker of your laptop. We talk about some small speaker found on motherboard (of tower pc for exmaple), that's used to signal boot error with beep sound. This does not exit a lot anymore, in laptop for example.

You can check if you have a **true PC Speaker** by looking at output of `alsamixer` or `amixer`, if you have alsa installed, and look for something like 'PC Speaker'

Your alternative is to use `aplay` and play a sound

`cat /dev/urandom > /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c` should work but it use your sound card, not the built-in-on-board-pc-speaker.

Comment: As I wrote, I am not sure there is a PC speaker, but there is a speaker connected *to the sound card*. As I wrote, I don't have `beep`. As I wrote, `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c` did not work. Sorry, but your "answer" provides no information whatsoever.

Comment: Then investigate why the last command does not work ? Why use urandom when aplay could tell you more why it does not work ? Does `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0c` even exist ?

Comment: From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28045/30206) it seems the error message is "normal". I don't have `aplay` either, as I also wrote in my question. Yes, `/dev/snd/pcmC0D0p` exists, that's why I tried it.