# How to cat a specific tone to /dev/audio?

Tags: command-line, audio, cat, random

- `cat /dev/urandom` generates a random sequence of all possibles "values".
- `cat /dev/urandom | padsp tee /dev/audio > /dev/null` directs these "values" to your audio device, turning them into "random noise" or "random tones" (see: [Generating random noise for fun in /dev/snd/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13732/generating-random-noise-for-fun-in-dev-snd))

But how can I do the same but instead of random noise/tones I pick a *single* value out of all possibles values and `cat` *that* to the audio device indefinitely (creating a sequence of the same value rather than random values)?

This should produce a single consistent tone.

### Interface

You can manually experiment with different values, but one imaginary "interface" to make it easier to pick/hit the value you want could be:

- **Frequency** (Hz) e.g. 440
- **Amplitude** (0 - 1) e.g. 0.8

---

I'd rather **not** use an audio *file*, e.g. file.wav, file.mp3, file.ogg, etc. Just a bash script and defaultish cli applications (e.g. `cat`, `padsp`, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play around with anything that can do maths (`sin` especially) and write a number as a character to stdout.  For example:

```
awk --characters-as-bytes 'BEGIN { freq=2200; amp=0.3; for (i=0; i>=0; i++) { printf "%c", 127+ amp*(127.0*sin(2*3.14159265/44100*i*freq)); } }' | padsp tee /dev/audio > /dev/null
```

Depending on how you set `freq` it sounds more like a siren...  perhaps that's something to play with, depending on your use case.

The amplitude is adjusted with `amp`, max 1.0.

Please note that I am using GNU awk, therefore `--characters-as-bytes` works.  You do not want characters to be UTF-8 encoded when written to stdout!

Also, depending on your system you may want to replace 44100 by 48000 or a different number if the default sample rate differs.

Comment: Can you make an interface/option for "volume" as well? Amplitude kind of functions as volume, but not exactly. In my testing amplitude kind of functions as volume from about 0.0 to 0.5, but beyond that it doesn't make much difference in terms of "perceived loudness".

Comment: @01AutoMonkey Funny, on my system the difference between 0.5 and 1.0 is very noticeable indeed! 1.0 is very loud, though, so unless you have your mixer tuned down a little you may hear distortions from clipping.